# Expression "IS NOT NULL" not working on HQL

Tags: null, hive, hql

When I do a select statement for non-null values on a hive table, there are no correct results in the response. The result is as if "is not null" expression is not there!

**Example**:

```
select count(*)
from test_table
where test_col_id1='12345' and test_col_id2 is not null;
```

Note `test_col_id1` and `test_col_id2` are not partition keys.

Here's my hive version.

> Hive 0.14.0.2.2.0.0-2041

Here's the table:

... | test_col_id1 | test_col_id2 | 
... | 12345 | x | 
... | 12345 | NULL |

This query returns 2 records.

Comment: What kind of SerDe are you using: Text, Sequence, AVRO, Parquet, ORC? And when you select a row with a value that you *think* is Null, does it show as "null" or as an empty string?

Comment: Which version of Hive? Using TEZ *(which version)* or plain MapReduce?

Comment: I'm doing the querying from command line. When I query the record, I see a **NULL** on the command line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following query, does it return rows?

```
select count(*)
from test_table
where test_col_id1='12345' and test_col_id2 != 'NULL';
```

Then your `NULL` is not `NULL`, it's the string 'NULL'. Loads of people have problems with Hive treatment of `NULL` strings. By default, it's the blank string `''`. If we want anything else, we have to specify exactly the way NULL strings should be treated when we create the table. Here are 3 examples of how to change what is recognized as `NULL`. The first one sets 'NULL' strings as `NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE nulltest1 (id STRING, another_string STRING)
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='NULL') --sets the string 'NULL' as NULL;
CREATE TABLE nulltest2 (id STRING, another_string STRING)
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='') --sets empty string as NULL;
CREATE TABLE nulltest3 (id STRING, another_string STRING)
TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='\N'); --sets \N as NULL;
```

Since you've already created your table, you can alter your table so that it will recognize your `'NULL'` as `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table SET TBLPROPERTIES ('serialization.null.format' = 'NULL');
```

Answer (score 4):

Hive parse NULL value in a different way.

Hive does not consider empty value is NULL. However, by default, Hive uses `\N` to represent 
NULL (not a special character, just backslash plus capital letter N). 
If you just want to filter out all the empty values, you can use

`where test_col_id2 != ''`

If you use the real NULL value in your original text file which was loaded into hive table, you can try

`where test_col_id2 != '\000'`

since the ASCII Code of NULL in octonary is 00 and the first "0" means it's an octonary number.

By the way, you can also use command:

```
alter table $YOUR_TABLE SETSERDEPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format' ='abc')
```

to customize the NULL value to "abc" if you want Hive to parse "abc" as the NULL value for some table.